# encontrar los 5 mayores numeros de un array en c#

Tags: c#, array

La pregunta es, si creo un arreglo, por ejemplo `int[] Arreglo = new int[10];`
y empiezo a almacenar datos en el, para sacar el mayor solo uso `Arreglo.max();`, pero para extraer no solo el mayor sino los 5 números mas alto como debería hacer?

Comment: Max es una funcion de extension de un array. Te recomiendo que empices pensando que hace max realmente, y asi vas a poder desarrollar tu propio algoritmo que traiga la cantidad de maximos que vos quieras. Para que podamos ayudarte, debes mostrar que intentaste y de ahi podemos tratar de ayudarte con tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mi esta es la forma mas sencilla con linq, teniendo en cuenta que no modificara el array original.

```
int[] myArray = new int[] {13, 5, 9, 6, 17, 5, 9, 3}; 

var array2 = myArray.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(5);
```

Es sencillo de comprender, primero organizamos el array de mayor a menor y luego tomamos los primeros 5.

Comment: En el caso de que se trate de un arreglo de tipo double no puedo ocupar la función OrderByDescending. ¿Qué podría hacer en ese caso entonces?

Answer (score 1):

Para estos casos lo mejor es usar LINQ ya que tiene funciones que ayudan mucho para resolver casos como tu problema.

En tu caso Array tiene una función que sirve para ordenar de forma descendente los valores de un array, a continuación te expongo un código que muestra en pantalla los cinco primeros números más altos del array.

```
// Declaración e inicialización del Array.
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 9, 6, 7, 5, 9}; 

// Ordena los valores del array de mayor a menor.
Array.Sort<int>(arr, new Comparison<int> (
    (i1, i2) => i2.CompareTo(i1)));

// Muestra los cinco primeros números en pantalla.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write(arr[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te animo a pasar por [answer] para ver como elaborar una respuesta de calidad. Lo correcto sería explicar al OP donde se encuentra el error o explicarle lo que pide.

Comment: Ahora es una respuesta mucho mejor, gracias por aportar y bienvenido a la comunidad :)

Comment: Como sugerencia, creo que es mejor que uses `OrderByDescending`, ya que con este método estás modificando el orden original del array, lo que puede no ser deseable. Yo haría algo como `var arrOrdenado= arr.OrderByDescending(x => x);`